# React state is updated but website still shows old state until manual refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to create a button to delete an employee. A dialog pop up will ask for confirmation and on confirmation, I will set the state of the list of employees using filter to remove the deleted employee and at the same time also send the deleted employee's ID to an API to delete from the backend database.

However, even though the data is deleted in the database and the `console.log()` of the updated list of employees shows that it does not include the deleted employee, the deleted employee still appear on the website until I manually refresh the page and then it will disappear.

Here is my code:

```
const onDeleteDialogConfirm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(deleteID);
    const filteredWorkers = workers.filter(el => el.employeeId !== deleteID);
    console.log(filteredWorkers);
    setWorkers(filteredWorkers);
    deleteWorkers(dispatch, deleteID)
    .then(() => setDialog(dispatch, deleteDialog))
    .catch(() => setDialog(dispatch, {
        ...deleteDialog,
        body: 'Deletion failed. Please retry.'
    }));
    
    setShowDeleteDialog(false);
}
```

```
export const deleteWorkers = async (dispatch, workerId) => {
    try {
        // a DELETE request to /employee/{workerId}
        await axios.delete(`${URL.rest.employee}/${workerId}`);

    } catch (err) {
        setError(dispatch, ERROR.worker);
    }
}
```

If I remove the `deleteWorkers` function from the `onDeleteDialogConfirm`, clicking on the delete confirmation button will instantly remove the deleted employee from the web page without refreshing. However, the data will not be deleted from the database.

Comment: What happens if you spread the array when setting it (i.e. ‘setWorkers([…filteredWorkers])’)?

Comment: it now displays only 2 employees, the employee before the deleted employee and the deleted employee

Comment: Were there 3 employees before?

Comment: There were 42 employees

Comment: my bad, I forgot the [] and used setWorkers(...filteredWorkers) instead.
I tried setWorkers([..filteredWorkers]) but it still shows the deleted employee with all the other 41 employees.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the rest of your code. If you’d like you can add a github link at the end of the question.

Comment: Even better if you upload a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's a bit complicated as it is part of a larger application. However, I realize it works after commenting out all the lines that use dispatch. Could be something related to Redux

Answer (score 1):

When setting an array or an object to a state in react it is good practice to spread the object or the array before setting it to the state. This is because react compares the old state to the new state using an `Object.is` comparison as is documented [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-the-screen-doesnt-update).

Since you’re updating the object itself, react sees that it is the same object as before and does not realize that the state has been updated.

This can be resolved by spreading the new array or object before setting the state. In your case the proper way to set the state would be `setWorkers([...filteredWorkers])` which sets an entire new object to the state. Since the entire object is now different this should now trigger a rerender.